# rails default scope with two values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is a beginner question, is this valid in rails?

```
default_scope { where(:arhiveeritud => false||nil).order('id') }
```

I need that `default_scope` check for `'arhiveeritud'` for **false and nil**.
I get a wrong result if it is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After almost 1 year and 10m later I want post better answer. When I'm a litter bit smarter.

Both @ray and @mrzasa answers are correct but it's create sql like this ...`WHERE (arhiveeritud IS false OR arhiveeritud IS NULL) ORDER BY id DESC`...

When can do better...We can use postgresql `COALESCE` for checking NULL and false

```
default_scope { where("COALESCE(arhiveeritud, false) = false").order('id') }
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can try following,

```
default_scope { where(arhiveeritud: [false, nil]).order('id') }
```

It is good practice to use pure active_record query over raw SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL `OR` in `where`:

```
default_scope { where("arhiveeritud = ? OR arhiveeritud IS NULL", false).order(:id) }
```

I would suggest thought to set a default false value on that field and run a migration if needed to fill in existing one. It's better to have consistent columns without `NULL`s esp. if it's a boolean column.

Comment: Thank you both for your time and quick response @mrzasa and @ray!